# AChartEngine live DialChart

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm heaving some troubles with dial chart from library AChartEngine. I implemented it already, but I don't know how to make it live (I'm changing values continuously, which i want to show on dial graph with one needle). I already have continuously changing line graph which I tried to modify to a dial graph, but I guess this one is a little different to do...

Anyone have any example?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be much different. You change the value in the series and then call `chartView.repaint();`